# how to encode Twilio SMS response message body

Tags: python, twilio

Upon receiving a SMS message from a phone handset, Twilio makes a HTTP request to a designated URL, passing the originating phone number, message body and some other parameters. It them expects a response such as for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
   <Message>Some text</Message>
</Response
```

In which case, a SMS message with text "Some text" is sent back by Twilio to the originating handset.
However, if the message text contains characters from for example scandinavian alphabet, ie. characters ä or ö (a umlaut & o umlaut), this does not work with the whole message encoded as UTF-8. The handset receives a message with the special characters garbled.

How should the response be encoded so the special characters in the response message are passed properly all the way back to the handset?

Comment: It could also be a problem specific to that handset. Try other mobiles as well

Comment: Hey, Twilio devangelist here. I see you're using Python. Have you done unicode conversion with the body of the message? On Python 2.* you have to do this manually, on Python 3 unicode is the default.